# Alternating header in scrreprt with scrpage2

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrpage2

I want to achieve the following:
In a twoside document I want to display the chapter title on even pages and the section (plus subsection if there is one) title on odd pages. So that for odd pages it looks like "section -- subsection" if there is a subsection and "section" otherwise.
So far, I do it this way:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright, appendixprefix, BCOR7.5mm, pointlessnumbers, bibliography=totoc, listof=totoc]{scrreprt}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[american]{babel}
    \usepackage{blindtext}

    \usepackage{scrpage2}

    \begin{document}

    \pagestyle{scrheadings}
    \automark[subsection]{chapter}
    \renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{%
        \markright{\ifnum \value{secnumdepth} >0 \sectionmarkformat\fi
        #1}}%
    \setheadsepline{.2pt}
    \ohead{\headmark}

    \chapter{Chapter 1}
    \section{section}
    \blindtext[15]

    \chapter{Chapter 2}
    \section{section}
    \subsection{subsection}
    \blindtext[15]

    \end{document}
```

This works so far in that it displays chapter and section OR subsections, respectively. Now I want to display both, section and subsection. How can I do this?
Thank you.

Edit: Added example.

Comment: Improve your question: Make a complete example. Also the title of your question says "scrartcl", but your question mentions `\chapter`.

Comment: Well, I am not sure what exactly I should write. I am using scrartcl as document class and scrpage2 to format my headers. Now I tried redefining `\sectionmark` so that it displays "section -- subsection" if a subsection exists and only "section" otherwise.

Comment: You should make a complete *example*. One that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and so enables us to make sensible tests.

Comment: I see. Well, this would be my example then. It basically does what I want but only displays the section OR subsection title and not both.

Comment: What would you want in the header if you have on one page "section, subsection, section". What if there is only a section? What if there is "subsection, section, subsection"?

Comment: Well, if there is a subsection of the current section, "section -- subsection" should be displayed. For the last case, always the latest section would be nice. If there is only a section, only the section title should be displayed.

Comment: I changed the title, as already requested by Ulrike, to be conform with your example.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright, appendixprefix, BCOR7.5mm, pointlessnumbers, bibliography=totoc, listof=totoc]{scrreprt}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[american]{babel}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{extramarks}
    \usepackage{scrpage2}
    \newcommand\currentsectionmark{}
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}
    \automark[subsection]{chapter}

    \renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{%
        \markright{\ifnum \value{secnumdepth} >0 \sectionmarkformat\fi
        #1}\def\currentsectionmark{\ifnum \value{secnumdepth} >0 \sectionmarkformat\fi
        #1}}%

    \renewcommand*\subsectionmark[1]{%
     \markright{\currentsectionmark\ -- \subsectionmarkformat #1}}    
    \setheadsepline{.2pt}
    \lehead{\leftmark}
    \rohead{\lastrightmark}

    \begin{document}


    \chapter{Chapter 1}
        blub
    \newpage
    blub
    \newpage
    \section{section}
    \section{section 2}
    \blindtext[15]

    \chapter{Chapter 2}
        blub
    \newpage
    blub
    \newpage
    \section{section}
    \section{section 2}
    \subsection{subsection}
    \blindtext[15]
    \chapter{Chapter 2}
    blub
    \newpage
    blub
    \newpage
    \section{section}
    \subsection{subsection}
    \section{section 2}
    \blindtext[15]

    \chapter{Chapter 2}
    blub
    \newpage
    blub
    \newpage
    \section{section}
    \newpage
    \subsection{subsection}
    \subsection{subsection 2}
    \blindtext[35]
    \end{document}
```